# How to create command that creates new if command?

Tags: macros, conditionals

I want to load parameters (for conditional compilation) from files. I wrote command **param** that creates new **if** command and read parameter from file, containing following line:

```
\paramnametrue % or false
```

My **param** command:

```
\newcommand{\param}[1]{\newif\if#1 \IfFileExists{#1}{\input{#1}}{}}
```

The problem is that when I write

```
\param{A}
```

outside of *document* environment I get

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
```

and inside of *document* environment I get

```
A
```

inside of my document.
How can I make it work? How can I create *not handling text* commands?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't build a control sequence name by simply typing `\if#1`, because `\if` is a single token.

You have a couple of possibilities. First one without packages:

```
\newcommand{\param}[1]{%
  \expandafter\newif\csname if#1\endcsname
  \IfFileExists{#1}{\input{#1}}{}%
}
```

This has the disadvantage that no check is performed if the conditional already exists. A second possibility is with `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\param}[1]{%
  \newboolean{#1}%
  \IfFileExists{#1}{\input{#1}}{}%
}
```

What `\newboolean` does is similar to `\newif`, so after `\param{A}` the conditional `\ifA` and the commands `\Atrue` and `\Afalse` will be defined. The same happens with the former solution, but here also a check for duplicate definitions is performed. If you don't want the check, then use `\provideboolean`.

Answer (score 12):

If `#1` is `A` then `\if#1` is not the single token `\ifA` it is the two tokens `\if A` so you end up redefining `\if` which is not good. You want

```
\expandafter\newif\csname if#1\endcsname
```

to construct the `\ifA` token and pass it to `\newif`

Comment: That was my idea, but I was trying it at http://www.tlhiv.org/ltxpreview/ and this: `\newcommand{\param}[1]{\expandafter\newif\csname if#1\endcsname}
\param{A}` produces the error `! Missing control sequence inserted.     inaccessible`, at least at this previewer. Why?

Comment: @JLDiaz no idea, presumably the document it sends to latex is not the document it shows you. The code in your comment works in latex.